# MySQL grouping columns

Tags: mysql

is there any way i can group several of my columns together?

in one for my scripts i need to set several of my columns to the same value, is there a better way than typing out all the column names in my update query?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these columns MUST always have the same value (that seems pointless) you could set an UPDATE TRIGGER on the column

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER somename BEFORE INSERT ON table1
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET table1.col2=NEW.col1, table1.col3=NEW.col1;
END;

delimiter ;
```

But if that was the case, it would really make sense to just use ONE column instead of three.

Or, if its a Rights issue (this user shouldn't have the permission to make the columns different) you could build a Stored Procedure for doing the update

```
delimiter |
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE somename(IN val INT,IN whereval INT)
 BEGIN
  UPDATE table1 SET table1.col1=val, table1.col2=val, table1.col3=val
    WHERE table1.id=whereval;
END;

delimiter ;
```

Comment: the columns don't always gave the same value, but quite often i need to reset the values of about 40 columns (4 groups of 10) to the same value, so some sort of grouping would be useful. i now see i could use a stored procedure to do this :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to type each column's name, there is no workaround.

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     col1 = 1,
        col2 = 1,
        …
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

See the [syntax for update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

```
...
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

[Update syntax for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) requires each column to be named explicitly

```
update table set a = 'value', b = 'value'
```